# Can't figure out what's wrong with this error: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=', in my Rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am getting this error:

```
comments_controller_spec.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
...ate, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment)}.to...
                           ^
```

when running my spec file comments_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe CommentsController do 

  describe "POST #create" do 
    comment = create(:comment)
    post = comment.post

    it "properly creates a comment" do 
      expect{post :create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment)}.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
    end

  end
end
```

which from what I can gather from reading other posts is that I haven't properly closed a block or hash.  I've been looking this over again and again and I can't find anything that isn't closed properly.  It seems to be pointing to my post method as the source of the problem, but I believe I have properly passed in all of it's arguments.  So I'm not sure what else could be wrong.  Can anyone tell what is going on here?  Thanks for the help.

Updated:

I changed the test to this:

```
it "properly creates a comment" do 

      expect {post(:create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment))}.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
end
```

and now the error message is:

```
CommentsController POST #create properly creates a comment
     Failure/Error: expect {post(:create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment))}.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
     # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and here is my post_factory.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

  factory :post do 
    content "this is post content!"
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: what happens if you wrap all your params in a hash ?, like this: `post :create, { post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment) }`.

Comment: I get this error instead: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'

Comment: what does `attributes_for` returns ?, perhaps that's where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `change` matcher expects a block:

```
expect{post :create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment)}.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
```

If that's not it, I would try adding brackets around the arguments to `post`, thinking perhaps the parser is having issues:

```
expect{ post(:create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment)) }.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
```

As a last resort, I would do:

```
expect do
  post(:create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment)) 
end.to change{ Comment.count }.by(1)
```

Comment: I changed it to use parentheses around the args like your second example, and now get this error: ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code and the full error message? Hard to know which method is expecting 0 arguments.

Comment: Note that the argument to the `change` as I posted it is a block, not two arguments like you have: `change{ Comment.count }` vs `change(Comment, :count)`

Comment: I still get the same error whether or not I use a block there

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
it "properly creates a comment" do 
  expect { post(:create, post_id: post.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment)) }.to change { Comment.count }.by(1)
end
```

Comment: I get the same error that I updated later in my post